# buildozer debug kivymd crashes on the splash screen

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

After executing the buildozer android debug deploy run logcat command, when the software tries to run on the phone, it exits the software on the splash screen and this long log is displayed(i summarized the log, there were about 3000 [debug], all almost the same):

```
05-20 10:02:35.531 29051 29082 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
05-20 10:02:35.531 29051 29082 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
05-20 10:02:35.531 29051 29082 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
05-20 10:02:35.531 29051 29082 I python  : /data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app
05-20 10:02:35.531 29051 29082 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
05-20 10:02:35.531 29051 29082 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
05-20 10:02:35.531 29051 29082 I python  : calculated paths to be...
05-20 10:02:35.531 29051 29082 I python  : /data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
05-20 10:02:35.532 29051 29082 I python  : set wchar paths...
05-20 10:02:35.560 29051 29082 I python  : Initialized python
05-20 10:02:35.560 29051 29082 I python  : AND: Init threads
05-20 10:02:35.560 29051 29082 I python  : testing python print redirection
05-20 10:02:35.561 29051 29082 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
05-20 10:02:35.561 29051 29082 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_ART_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.art', 'ANDROID_I18N_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.i18n', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework-graphics.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/apex/com.android.i18n/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/com.nxp.nfc.nq.pn553.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/system/framework/miui-framework.jar:/system/framework/miui-telephony-common.jar:/apex/com.android.appsearch/javalib/framework-appsearch.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.ipsec/javalib/android.net.ipsec.ike.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar:/apex/com.android.mediaprovider/javalib/framework-mediaprovider.jar:/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/framework-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission-s.jar:/apex/com.android.scheduling/javalib/framework-scheduling.jar:/apex/com.android.sdkext/javalib/framework-sdkextensions.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-connectivity.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-tethering.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/framework-wifi.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework-graphics.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/apex/com.android.i18n/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/com.nxp.nfc.nq.pn553.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/system/framework/miui-framework.jar:/system/framework/miui-telephony-common.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/miui.services.jar:/system/framework/miui-services.jar:/apex/com.android.appsearch/javalib/service-appsearch.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/service-art.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/service-media-s.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/service-permission.jar', 'STANDALONE_SYSTEMSERVER_JARS': '/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/service-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.scheduling/javalib/service-scheduling.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/service-connectivity.jar', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '18', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_primary': '22', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/
05-20 10:02:35.561 29051 29082 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
05-20 10:02:35.561 29051 29082 I python  : AND: Ran string
05-20 10:02:35.561 29051 29082 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
05-20 10:02:35.626 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-05-20_4.txt
05-20 10:02:35.626 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.0rc1
05-20 10:02:35.626 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
05-20 10:02:35.627 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.9 (main, May 20 2023, 01:21:34) 
05-20 10:02:35.627 29051 29082 I python  : [Clang 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb
05-20 10:02:35.627 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
05-20 10:02:35.627 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
05-20 10:02:35.627 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
05-20 10:02:35.628 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-05-17 (installed at "/data/user/0/app.hamta.spy/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.pyc")
05-20 10:02:35.630 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
05-20 10:02:35.660 29051 29082 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [autoclass(android.os.Build$VERSION) intf False hierarchy is [(<Class] java.lang.Object at 0x7005ae84a0>, 1), (<Class: android.os.Build$VERSION at 0x700783f270>, 0)]
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  : meth       ] identityHashCode
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   sig: (Ljava/lang/Object;)I
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Public False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Private False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Protected False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Static True
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Final False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Synchronized False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Volatile False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Transient False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Native False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Interface False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Abstract False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  :   Strict False
05-20 10:02:35.662 29051 29082 I python  : 
...
...
...
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  : meth       ] setHarmfulAppWarning
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   sig: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Public True
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Private False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Protected False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Static False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Final False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Synchronized False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Volatile False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Transient False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Native False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Interface False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Abstract False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  :   Strict False
05-20 10:02:36.256 29051 29082 I python  : 
...
...
...
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  : meth       ] updateFrom
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   sig: (Landroid/content/res/Configuration;)I
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Public True
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Private False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Protected False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Static False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Final False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Synchronized False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Volatile False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Transient False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Native False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Interface False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Abstract False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  :   Strict False
05-20 10:02:36.791 29051 29082 I python  : 
05-20 10:02:36.831 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_android, audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
05-20 10:02:36.980 29051 29082 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
05-20 10:02:36.981 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
05-20 10:02:36.984 29051 29082 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

And this is what I changed in my buildozer.spec file:

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = Spy

# (str) Package name
package.name = spy

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = app.hamta

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,sqlite,mp3

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,Controller/*,Model/*,Utility/*,View/*,libs/*

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy==master,KivyMD, arabic-reshaper, certifi, charset-normalizer, docutils, idna, Kivy-Garden, Pillow, Pygments, python-bidi, python-dateutil, pytz, requests, six, tzdata, urllib3

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
requirements.source.kivymd = venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivymd/

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.1.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
#android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)
android.permissions = android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 33

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
#android.minapi = 24

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 33

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 25b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 24
```

Before this in this line:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy==master,KivyMD, arabic-reshaper, certifi, charset-normalizer, docutils, idna, Kivy-Garden, Pillow, Pygments, python-bidi, python-dateutil, pytz, requests, six, tzdata, urllib3
```

I tried it once with just kivy (not kivy==master) but the result was no different except that these infinite debugs were not displayed. I don't know where the problem is

ubuntu 22.04.2 in virtualbox.

kivy==2.1.0 kivymd==1.1.1